#  Select Childs of a div with dynamic id by jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

look at this guys:

```
<div id="Item_23">
 <div class="Info">
   <a class="Link" href="#" onclick="call(23)">Link</a>
   <div class="text">
     <a class="cancel" href="cancel.asp">Cancel</a>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Parent div have dynamic id and its digit part is variable.
Now, i want to select one of this child by class of course in a function. How can do it?

```
function call(e)
    // Selecting a.cancel
end function
```

Comment: Your function should work if the `e` parameter has an underscore in it. Otherwise make it like `$('div[id=Item_' + e + '] div.text).fadeOut()`

Comment: Yes, it only needs an underscore.

Comment: OK, IF my div.text has a child, how can select that?

Comment: Put it in your markup so we can see, then explain what you're trying to do with it.

Comment: See my answer, it selects .cancel for the specified item ID.

Comment: You don't need `ids`. You can remove the `onClick` attribute and use `jQuery` click method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Perhaps something like</strike>

```
$('div[id^=Item_] div.text');
```

or

```
$('div[id^=Item_] a.Link');
```

**In response to your edit**

Try this

```
function call(e) {

    // Find the inner anchor
    var theAnchor = $('div[id=Item_' + e + '] div.text').find('a.cancel');
}
```

You're missing the underscore in either your call or your jQuery code so it is looking for a div which has the ID

```
Item23
```

rather than the ID

```
Item_23
```

Here is a JSFiddle which demonstrates getting the cancel link when the other link is clicked.

http://jsfiddle.net/PyDKg/14/

As @undefined suggested, you don't need the inline javascript call since you're using jQuery. I have changed the function a bit so it just gets the ID of the parent and sends the entire ID as a parameter.

**HTML**

```
<div id="Item_23">
    <div class="Info">
        <a class="Link" href="#">Link</a>
        <div class="text">
            <a class="cancel" href="cancel.asp" data-val="Yay got it!">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.Link').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).parents('div[id^=Item_]').attr('id');
        callAnchor(id);
    });
});

function callAnchor(e) {

    // Find the inner anchor
    var theAnchor = $('div[id=' + e + '] div.Info div.text').find('a.cancel');

    // Print the data-val attribute to prove that it was found.
    alert($(theAnchor).attr('data-val'));
}
```

Comment: Oh my God, I'm so sorry, bad writing, Please see my edited code with SHY

Comment: Thank You so much James and pardon me for my mistake :)

Answer (score -1):

First, fix your original selector like so:

```
 var item = $('div[id=Item_' + e + '] div');
```

There are many ways to select a child element including [`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) and [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/), however this is the simplest and least likely to break with markup changes:

```
item.find('.Link');
```

Comment: _Parent div have dynamic id and its digit part is variable_